# Particle missing in 'こんなにおいしいの食べたことありません'

Tags: particles

I saw following sentence in one text book

こんなにおいしいの食べたことありません

But I would expect

こんなにおいしいの**は**食べたこと**が**ありません

Can both 'は' and 'が' be omitted here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can be omitted, especially in daily conversation. Particle is often omitted in daily conversation.

For example, A:刺身食べたことある?, B:(刺身)食べたことないよ.